# event listener function does not get updated useState values

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, frontend, use-effect, use-state

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event) => {
      if (event.code === "Enter" || event.code === "NumpadEnter") {
        console.log(email, password);
        login({ email, password }, dispatch);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
    };
  }, []);
```

Using the console.log to inspect I saw that `password` and `email` are always the initial values, even though the were changed.

Why doesn't the event handler able to get the updated values?

Comment: Because it's closed over those initial values, and you've explicitly said it should only be created once. How did you expect it to get access to the new ones?

Comment: But  I also tried to extract the `login({ email, password }, dispatch)` into its own function outside of the `useEffect` callback and then call it inside of the `useEffect`. That also didn't work.

Comment: It's hard to tell you why what you haven't shown doesn't work, but in general if you get the old values it's a closure problem.